# Migrating a closed question without re-opening

Tags: feature-request, migration

Can we make this possible?

As new area51 websites are being opened and going out of beta, some old closed questions on SO can now be moved to a more appropriate website, but not without reopening them first (which is unlikely to happen).

It would say:

```
link | edit | reopen | migrate (2) | flag
```

Comment: Obviously, once migrated the question will also be automatically reopened on the target site.

Comment: I like this idea in principle. How would this work with brand new questions? Would the "migrate" vote only appear if the question is closed as off-topic? It would somewhat circumvent the democratic process if 5 people vote to migrate *after* quorum was *not* reached to migrate initially.

Comment: @Jon: it would appear if closed for any reason, since many subjective questions are closed as "not a real question" (which could be moved to programmers), or "subjective and argumentative" (same as above). Yes, the migrate would appear only after the question is closed.

Answer (score 4):

A danger with this is that the question has been reasked on the new site, thus migration would cause a duplicate question.

Comment: Isn't it a danger in all cases?

Comment: @Kop - Yes, but new questions are more likely to be asked on the correct site and if the site makes it out of beta and if a migration path is set up there's no problem.

Comment: Well, in any case if this happens the question can be closed as duplicate, and the duplicate will be around on the **correct** website where it can show up in search results, so I don't think it's that bad.