# Vote to migrate closed questions

Tags: feature-request, migration, closed-questions

There are closed questions that due to different considerations (not enough initial migration votes, question closed before an available Stack Exchange migration alternative went live, etc) were simply closed and not migrated (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335632/should-i-use-a-64-bit-or-32-bit-linux-for-a-high-throughput-lamp-server).

Could we have a feature to propose closed questions for migration? In time, as more Stack Exchange sites go live, there will be more alternatives to migrate to, and on-topic closed questions may be migrated and used to seed those communities.

Comment: That question is 5 months old. What good would it do to migrate a punch of old (and most likely inactive) questions? *And that question was closed with such a force that it's jammed shut.*

Comment: If it's closed, it's probably closed for a good reason. It would likely add nothing of value to the target site. You could always drop into the a chat room of the target site and ask if it would be on-topic but, ultimately, it's probably not something worth worrying about. Of course, I expect there are exceptions, but we'll cross that bridge if we come to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Migrating a closed question without re-opening](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71190/migrating-a-closed-question-without-re-opening)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Migrating old questions usually does not make much sense, if you are still convinced that a closed question should be migrated you can flag it for moderator attention. Moderators can migrate any question to any site.

Migrations are pretty hard to get right, you need to know the target site reasonably well to make a good decision whether to migrate or not. That is one of the reasons why only the most common migration paths are enabled and any other migration needs to go through a moderator, who can easily ask the moderators of the target site if the question is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

What is the other Stack Exchange site where you are an active user, and where you want the question to be? Remember the golden rule of migrations:

**Migration is “we want this”, not “fob it off to them”.**

(From which we can deduce Jeff's first law of migrations as a corollary: don't migrate crud.)

This isn't a very good question to begin with (the answer is “it depends on parameters that you haven't given”). And you're looking at it from an SO perspective anyway, so you have no standing to migrate it: you'd be sending it away to some other site that you don't know so well. For an old question, where the asker isn't eagerly waiting for an answer anyway, it's really important to regard migration as *pulling towards you*, not as sending away.

Answer (score -3):

I've seen *new* questions getting unceremoniously closed as off-topic because the voters apparently didn't want to do the research to find out which of the 2-dozen-plus communities it was on-topic for. This actually happened to [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697164/give-the-exact-value-of-s-as-a-function-of-n-in-closed-form/697274#697274) to which I had already given what both I and the OP thought was an appropriate answer. I don't know the statistics regarding this, but I would venture a guess that many of the questions that should be migrated get closed instead. When there is a community which fields such a question and the voters know this, voting to close the question is simply lazy: let the OP figure out where the question belongs and repost it. In my opinion, this is irresponsible and impolite.

Comment: If those questions doesn't meet the "don't migrate crap" rule, nobody is going to migrate it.

Comment: And voting to migrate it, without being 100% sure it belongs on the target site is a big no no. In that case a "it doesn't belong here" vote is just fine.

Comment: @Braiam That's what the Meta community is for: if we don't like an SE policy, we can express our dissent. In my opinion it doesn't exactly put out the welcome mat to the user if we don't at least give him a chance to get his question answered!

Comment: Yeah, and I expressed my dissent about your opinion. Yup, the system works.

Comment: @Bart if we're at least 50% sure it belongs in that community, at least the question lives to see another day.

Comment: Or you've annoyed another site with a question which is off-topic, gets closed there as well, shoved back to the site of origin, where it will most likely die. So nope, don't migrate if you're not sure.

Comment: @Braiam OK Mr. Bandwagon, if we can't effect policy change because we're always voted down, then why is Meta SE even there in the first place?

Comment: @Bart if a question is well constructed but off topic for one community, it should be welcomed by the other one because they will know the answer. And closing a question just because it annoys you is not cool.

Comment: I don't close questions because they annoy me. I close questions because they are off-topic, for whatever reason. If it is on-topic in another community, that is great. If I know it is, and am 100% sure of that, I'll vote to migrate or ask a moderator to do so if there is no path for it. If I'm not sure, I might recommend the OP to go look at the other site, but will not vote to migrate it there. I know about the site I'm on, but might not know about the other sites. That is not laziness, that is not me being annoyed, it's merely proper practice.

Comment: You need to read Gilles answer, migration is not "shove this to them" but "we want this" (in the target site). So, unless you have confirmation or certainly that the other site won't come and hunt you down for migrating crap, heck, just don't do it.

Comment: @Braiam 1. the only reason to migrate a question is if the question is off topic, and 2. there are questions which get closed that clearly are on topic for another site. Also, 3. sometimes a question gets closed as off topic because it's poorly worded, whereas if the same question were reworded it would be on topic. [(Example)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697164/give-the-exact-value-of-s-as-a-function-of-n-in-closed-form)

Comment: And your point is?

Comment: @bart My point is I thought about submitting this as a question but when I saw this similar question, I figured I'd throw my support behind it. But I'm guessing from the negative votes that I made the wrong choice.

Comment: The choice is fine. The post is just disagreed with. That's all.